# using programs like tinymce and ckeditor in ipad programming

Tags: ipad, text, tinymce, ckeditor, processor

I'm developing an application in ipad that requires a word processor functionality and since uitextview is very limited I want to use tinymce or ckeditor especially with iOS 5 being released. However when I try to load these api's index.html page in a uiwebview, the toolbar items don't show up (copy, paste, bold, ...) and the text has all the tags shown. Do I have to edit something in the index.html page or do I have to modify the javascripts or other files for it to work with uiwebview? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the latest TinyMCE [Full Feature demo](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) on an iPad running iOS5 and Safari and found no problems.

As I understand it earlier versions didn't recognise Safari on iOS as a supported platform so it may be possible you are using one of those.

Comment: well using the safari to browse to the page with the demo works perfectly, but when I download their demo and try to load the index.html file in the uiwebview, the icons don't show up and all the tags are shown.

Comment: i had no problems surfing the demo page, but when used in our own CMS i had problems pushing tinymce UI buttons when the keyboard was shown and pushing buttons or checkboxes took a lot of time